# How to parse JSON from localhost?

Tags: android, json, localhost, android-logcat

I'm trying to parse data from my local host which is [{"data":{"statues":"2"}}].

This is my code for JSON:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
             for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     Log.i("log_tag","statues: "+json_data.getString("statues"));
                     //Get an output to the screen
                    returnString = json_data.getString("statues");
                     tv.setText(returnString);
```

Everything sounds ok, but in my log-cat, this error occurs:

```
11-15 09:07:27.403: E/log_tag(3037): Error in http connection!!org.json.JSONException: Value [{"data":{"statues":"2"}}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I say it sounds ok because it catches the statues, but not its value (which is 2).
I also tried `json_data.getInt("statues");` , but the problem is still the same.

What should I do?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     JSONObject c = json_data.getJSONObject("data");
                     Log.i("log_tag","statues: "+c.getString("statues"));
                     //Get an output to the screen
                    returnString = c.getString("statues");
                     tv.setText(returnString);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>()`;

Take a look at this:
[How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

you have to get `JSONObject` like this

```
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
   JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

    // Storing each json item in variable
    String id = c.getString("identifier1");
    String name = c.getString("identifier2");

}
```

for more details you can use this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)